# Make rebuilding without any modifications

Tags: makefile

I've started writing a couple of simple tests for a library. I am currently trying to write a make target called `btests` that is supposed to compile them all.

The tests reside in the `tests/` directory in the form of simple `.cpp` files which `#include` the library.

The makefile's task is simple: compile each `tests/name.cpp` into an executable `tests/name` file which has been linked with the library.

And it works fine, except one thing: each time I run `make btests`, tests get recompiled. However, they should recompile only if they have been changed or the library itself has been changed.

This is the relevant code:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-Wall

SRCPATH=source
OBJPATH=object
TESTPATH=tests

OBJ=$(OBJPATH)/nameb.o $(OBJPATH)/hebbann.o
INF=$(SRCPATH)/nameb.hpp $(SRCPATH)/hebbann.hpp
TESTS=$(TESTPATH)/test_api $(TESTPATH)/test_speed


all : libname.a

libname.a : $(OBJ)
    ar rvs libname.a $(OBJ)

$(OBJ) : $(OBJPATH)/%.o : $(SRCPATH)/%.cpp $(SRCPATH)/%.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

btests : $(TESTS)

$(TESTS) : % : %.cpp all
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -L. -lname -o $@

install : all
    mkdir -p /usr/include/name
    cp $(INF) /usr/include/name
    cp libname.a /usr/lib

pack : all
    mkdir -p name/
    cp $(INF) name/
    tar -cvf libname.tar name/ libname.a doc/ source/

clean :
    rm -f $(OBJPATH)/* libname.a libname.tar $(TESTS)
```

How can I force make to recompile only when something has changed?

Comment: That makefile looks fine - is it really the one you're using?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem; are you sure this is the makefile you're using, and that there's nothing else that could be messing with last-modified times of various files?

Comment: Well I trimmed off the parts that seemed irrelevant to me, but I guess they're not. I'll add the whole makefile.

Comment: Use make -d to learn what it's thinking.

Comment: Why do you have the TESTS target depending on everything (the percent sign)?  Wouldn't this make the TESTS target sensitive to any file change?

Comment: @AB: no, it's just a wildcard that's substituted for each element in TESTS in turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tests depend on `all`. Since there is no file called "all", Make concludes that it must be rebuilt, and so must the tests that depend on it.

The fix is simple. The rule for `all` does nothing but require `libname.a`, so just cut out the middleman:

```
$(TESTS) : % : %.cpp libname.a
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -L. -lname -o $@
```